# Why won't my axios request return the proper data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have an api running at the url used in my axios instance. A route is defined for login that returns JWT access and refresh tokens if valid credentials are provided. I can test it using postman and everything works great, but in my app using axios no tokens or error gets returned even with valid credentials. The API is setup for cors also and is running live.

here is the axios instance:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url = NOT SHOWN;

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: url,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

here is the basic login component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link as RouteLink, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import axiosInstance from '../../axiosInstance';

//material ui
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';

class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    isAuthenticated: false,
  };

  login(email, password) {
    const data = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };
    axiosInstance
      .post('/login', data)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    this.login(email, password);
  };

  onChange = (e) => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim() });

  render() {
    if (this.state.isAuthenticated) {
      return <Redirect to='/' />;
    }
    return (
      <Container component='main' maxWidth='xs' style={{ marginTop: '75px' }}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <div>
          <Typography component='h1' variant='h3' align='center'>
            Login
          </Typography>
          <form noValidate>
            <TextField
              variant='outlined'
              margin='normal'
              required
              fullWidth
              id='email'
              label='Email Address'
              name='email'
              autoComplete='email'
              autoFocus
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <TextField
              variant='outlined'
              margin='normal'
              required
              fullWidth
              name='password'
              label='Password'
              type='password'
              id='password'
              autoComplete='current-password'
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              control={<Checkbox value='remember' color='primary' />}
              label='Remember me'
            />
            <Button
              type='submit'
              fullWidth
              variant='contained'
              color='primary'
              //className={classes.submit}
              onClick={this.onSubmit}
            >
              LOGIN
            </Button>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs>
                <Link variant='body2'>Forgot password?</Link>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <Link component={RouteLink} to={'/signup'} variant='body2'>
                  {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                </Link>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

'''

Comment: Do you see the request being made in your browser's dev-tools? If you can see it, does it have the correct payload (`email` and `password`)? What does the response look like (in the dev-tools _Network -> Response_ tab)?

Comment: Because your login function uses the state of class. You need to bind login function with this keyword. this.login =  this.login.bind(this)  in your constructor

Comment: @Phil in the browser dev-tools the request seems to never hit the server and I get a NS_BINDING_ABORTED error with the post request

Comment: figured it out for anyone who comes across this. In my login route (server side) I was looking for 'email' and 'password' in the body, but on client side I was sending email and password inside the data object I create in the login function.

Comment: @stinny your comment makes no sense. You are posting a JSON request body with `email` and `password` properties. What exactly is your server-side code trying to do with that? Where was the mistake? What did you do to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

I believe the login function is not defined properly so it is not being called. Please try using a function expression:

```
login = (email, password) => {
    const data = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };
    axiosInstance
      .post('/login', data)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    login(email, password);
  };
```